# Chose encoding of character literals based on templates ion C++

Tags: c++, encoding

I'm trying to write an RFC 3986 compliant URL parser. Now I'm not so proficient when it comes to character encoding, but after a while I came to the conclusion that I probably don't have to take encoding into account if I'm only parsing and storing the url (it's a whole different story if I was to actually perform DNS lookup and network transmission). So basically the percent-encoding specified by RFC3986 will be applied on top of the underlying string encoding.

There's one exception that could break this however. Say some crazy embedded engineer tries to compile the code with say EBCDIC encoding, while the url (maybe passed from outside) would remain UTF-8. Now my parser comparisons u8"/" == ebcdic"/" wouldn't hold anymore and the parsing would be off. My idea was to fix this by letting the user choose the encoding of the url format so that the comparisons will always hold. But I see no way to do it? Basically I would need to template string literals on the encoding type

```
template<??? Encoding>
char del = Encoding"/";
```

Is this somehow doable or are there alternatives?

Comment: *"EBCDIC encoding"* Simply don't bother. It's only slightly less improbable than "what if `CHAR_BIT == 13`", etc. Do your research first. Do modern compilers for those platforms exist? Something tells me that even if they do, people using them don't expect third-party libs to support them.

Comment: In your quest to chase genericity over an ever increasing set of requirements, you'd have to stop somewhere, otherwise you'll end up trying to handle the martian convention for urls starting with `n*̶͑̾̾̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅s`. Stopping at utf8 is fine.

Comment: @PasserBy Thanks for relieving me of this burden, I tend to overthink it.. ;D But it has led me down an interesting rabbithole.

Comment: The exact syntax you want is not possible, but there's user defined literals where you can call arbitrary conversion functions, including `constexpr` ones. For templated variables, you can do `auto del = convert<Encoding>("/");`